# Search a value with parenthesis in Datatable search not giving the result

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have the following code which is used to create the datatble and filter the value, but when the value contains parenthesis then the search is not giving any result though value can be seen if I chose to see All.

I have used both the

```
column.search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
```

and

```
var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                         $(this).val()
                                     );
```

But it is not able to search the value with parenthesis.

Below is the full code snippet

```
initComplete: function () {
                         this.api().columns([1,2,3,4,5,6]).every(function () {
                         var column = this;
                         var select = $('<select style="width:130px; font-size: 13px;text-align-last: center; padding: 2px 1px 2px 1px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 6px;position: relative; "><option value="">(All)</option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.footer()))
                          .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                                 .on('change', function () {
                                     var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                         $(this).val()
                                     );
                                    alert("Asche::"+val);
                                     column
                                         .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                         .draw();
                                 });
                             column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                                 select.append('<option style="text-align-last: right;" value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    } );
                } );
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried to URLEncode the search value?

Comment: No I have not tried that. So for this then no need for the below  var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                         $(this).val()
                                     );

Answer (score 0):

replace $(this).val with

```
$(this).val().replace(/\+/g,'\\+').replace(/\(/g,'\\(').replace(/\)/g,'\\)')
```

it works for me